# Issue with opening oracle form you must install the J2SE Plugin version

Tags: java, oracle, plugins, version

I  working on an application where want to open oracle form but every time it shows message like this

```
In order to access this application, you must install the J2SE Plugin version 1.6.0_07. To install this plugin, click here to download the oaj2se.exe executable. Once the download is complete, double-click the oaj2se.exe file to install the plugin. You will be prompted to restart your browser when the installation is complete.
```

and I download many versions of java as you can see in the picture
[image: here picture on java versions I tried and download]

ever uninstall and install of version
I restart my computer
but still gets the same problem

my system is Windows7
64 bit
,I also try disable security program
take a look at my programs from control panel
to check if there is any conflicts

[image: here picture of my programs from control panel]

Comment: Which browser are you using to access the form?

Comment: I try with firefox, IE , and google chrome

Answer (score 0):

After installing this file oaj2se.exe.

U need to enable java in your browser. For the detailed instructions on how to enable java for different browsers is given here.

https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

A sample screen shot in Mozilla
[Link for screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaN40.png)

After enabling u need to add an exception list in your java control panel.

Java Configure->Security-> Add exception list
Paste the link in the exception list.

[Click on the link to see how to add exception list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvYnt.png)

Hope this helps.